# How to tell if a group of items is stacked horizontally or vertically based only on their positions?

Tags: algorithms, programming-practices, organization

How do you tell if a group of items is stacked horizontally or vertically given only the items x and y positions?

Vertical Group:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

Horizontal Group:

• item 1 • item 2 • item 3

The items in the vertical stack can be moved left or right but each item is further down from the last.

The items in a horizontal stack can be higher up or lower down than the first item.

What I'm doing now to check for a vertical stack is to check if the second item Y position is greater than the first item Y position. But if it is a horizontal group of items and the items are stair-cased down from top to bottom then it would fail.

```
    if (secondItemY>topY) {
        return true;
    }
```

I almost had it figured out

**More info:**
Items can be left or right of each other, the second item never overlaps the first item. The second item top position will always be at least the previous item top plus height. There can be gaps between items or no gap at all. Items can be different sizes. They can be different shapes but have rectangular bounds. There is no ordering.

You can think about it and test it as a list of items on a web page in a group. Except in the web page you can have negative margins between items (I think) where in my case you cannot.

**Update**:
FYI I haven’t accepted my own answer post until I have tested it more. I’d also like to add examples to it to show it working (or not).

Comment: Polar coordinates might be useful to you

Comment: This is no time to be talking about the plight of our northern furry friends although their story is tragic and endearing

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/what-is-the-equation-used-to-calculate-a-linear-trendline

Comment: Why can't they be both or neither?

Comment: Your definitions seem to be ambiguous.  If you arrange them in s staircase, then they are both horizontal and vertical at the same time.

Comment: Can the items overlap?

Comment: _"The items in the vertical stack can be moved left or right but each item is further down from the last."_ Notice how you did not quanitify **how much** things are shifted left/right and up/down; and the difference between the two. That is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what seems to work. Here's the pseudocode:

- Loop through each item from first to last
- Check if the x or y increases after each item
- If y increases until the last item then it is vertical (probably)
- If x increases until the last item then it is not vertical (probably)
- [Previous step:] If they both increase (staircase) then check if the height of the group is taller than the width of the group (meaning portrait or vertical layout).
- Edit: The above fails when there are only two items. Now, if both increase check if the Y difference between the two items is greater than the X difference. Then fall back on isPortrait().

It's not 100% fool proof. If you have a square and each item is positioned in a staircase there is no way to tell if it's vertical or horizontal.

```
function isVerticalLayout(group) {
    var items = group.children;
    var numberOfItems = items.length;
    var secondItem = null;
    var item = null;
    var itemX = 0;
    var itemY = 0;
    var secondItemX = 0;
    var secondItemY = 0;
    var xGrows = true;
    var yGrows = true;

    if (numberOfItems>1) {

        // use a for loop to iterate from first to last item
        for (var i=numberOfItems-1;i>-1;i--) {
            item = items[i];
            secondItem = items[i-1];
        
            itemX = item.x;
            itemY = item.y;
        
            if (secondItem) {
                secondItemX = secondItem.x;
                secondItemY = secondItem.y;
            }
            else {
                continue; // is last item - exit
            }

            xOffset = secondItemX-itemX;
            yOffset = secondItemY-itemY;

            if (secondItemY>itemY) {

            }
            else {
                yGrows = false;
            }

            if (secondItemX>itemX) {

            }
            else {
                xGrows = false;
            }
        }
    
        // the rare and elusive stair-case layout
        if (xGrows && yGrows) {
            if (yOffset>xOffset) {
                return true;
            }

            return isPortrait(group); // is group height greater than width
        }

        // horizontal 
        if (xGrows) {
            return false;
        }
    
        // vertical
        if (yGrows) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the items are actually non-overlapping rectangles. And you would consider them horizontally stacked if their x-coordinates don't overlap.

Then in pseudo-code that would be something like this:

```
bool are_items_horizontally_stacked( rectangle[] items )
{
   rectangle[] sortedrectangles = sort_by_min_x( items );
   for (int i = 0 to sortedrectangles.size()-2)
   {
     if (sortedrectangle[I].max_x > sortedrectangle[i+1].min_x)
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
bool are_items_vertically_stacked( rectangle[] items )
{
   rectangle[] sortedrectangles = sort_by_min_y( items );
   for (int i = 0 to sortedrectangles.size()-2)
   {
     if (sortedrectangle[i].max_y > sortedrectangle[i+1].min_y)
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Note that certain sets of items could be neither horizontally nor vertically stacked, or both at the same time (eg. in case they are diagonally aligned).  Note that a set of 0 or 1 items is always considered both horizontally and vertically stacked. If that is not the intention, then please clarify the expected output for all these cases.

Comment: Items can be left or right of each other, the second item never overlaps the first item. The second item top position will always be at least the previous item to plus height. There can be gaps between items or no gap at all. Items can be different sizes. They can be different shapes but have rectangular bounds. There is no ordering.